# Speech recognition desktop technologies

Tags: speech-recognition

I'm not sure Stackoverflow is right place to ask for this. Please, guide me to the right place if it isn't.

I would like to make a script that would run and listen to my voice and recognize what I say.

It would have some exact commands, like "play my music" or so.

To me it looks like I will have 3 different part in this project:

1. one to listen and write a sound file
2. another one to translate the sound file to text
3. and a last one to compare the text to a command (would be nice if it could match "play my music" as well as "play some music pls")

I have made some researches, but it's a bit over my understanding. [This post](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/367979) could be my starting point but it's already 3 years old.

I assume many new technologies came out since then and I would like to hear what you guys know about it.

Regarding the technologies, I'm willing to use any that is necessary, but not .NET and I would like to avoid JAVA. Performance is not an issue, I'll favorite simplicity over performance.
I'm working on a Mac and I would like it to run in a Mac and a linux environment as well.

I will host it on Github in a public repository, so any pricy solution can't be (just saying).

Answer (score 1):

here is a [little project](https://github.com/klutometis/speech-recognition) that uses google speech api to perform steps 1 and 2.

it is written in clojure which is a lisp-like language hosted on the jvm.
The entire project is just [one short file](https://github.com/klutometis/speech-recognition/blob/master/src/speech_recognition/hear.clj), check it out.

Comment: Using google speech api is a start! First time I hear about this language!